# Simple matrix operation - element Part[`] from list

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a matrix `M=RandomReal[{0},{5,5,5}];`
How can I identify elements with a list?

Expected

`In[81]:= M[[5,5,5]]`

`Out[81]= 0.`

`M[[#]]&/@{{5,5,5}}` Doesn't work, no matter how much `Flatten[]`

There has to be an easier way than

```
In[83]:= a={2,2,2}
Out[83]= {2,2,2}
In[87]:= M[[a[[1]],a[[2]],a[[3]]]]
Out[87]= 0.
```

Apologies, I know there is probably a extremely simple answer...
Thanks for anyone who takes a look.

Edit* I would also like to adjust the identified element which has given a number of errors. `M[[{5,5,5}]]=1` Using @J.M. s solution

```
In[7]:= M2[[##]] & @@ allcells[[-1]] = +1

During evaluation of In[7]:= Set::write: Tag Apply in (M2[[##1]]&)@@{5,5,5} is Protected.

Out[7]= 1
```

Comment: Try `M[[##]] & @@ {5,5,5}`.

Comment: @J.M. Awh! Awesome! Thanks a lot


just for complete I'm using `M[[##]] & @@@ {{5,5,5},{4,4,4},{5,4,5}}`

but I doff my dunce cap'

Comment: If you figured out how it works, I invite you to write an answer to your own question. ;)

Comment: You might also want have a look at `Extract`. For example, `Extract[M, {{5, 5, 5}}]` returns `{0.}`. This might seem to be artificial, but `Extract` also works with lists of lists, e.g. `idx = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {10, 3}];
Extract[M, idx]`. In this case, you may also use `M[[##]] & @@@ idx`, but this unpacks arrays and is thus several magnitudes slower than `Extract`.

Comment: @J.M.
@HenrikSchumacher
How can I edit the element? I seem to be getting an error
`In[7]:= M[[##]] & @@ a[[-1]] = +1

During evaluation of In[7]:= Set::write: Tag Apply in (M[[##1]]&)@@{5,5,5} is Protected.

Out[7]= 1`

Comment: That's a different problem from what you asked.

Comment: @J.M. You wouldn't happen to know a solution?

Comment: Only solution I can come up with is 
`M[[a[[-1, 1]], a[[-1, 2]], a[[-1, 3]]]] = 1;`

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental difference here, though subtle yet important, is between `M[[a,b,c]]` and `M[[{a,b,c}]]`, the key part being (pun not intended) the curly brackets around `a,b,c`.

The first one gives what you want, and it's even in the form of your "expected" code, whereas the second one deals with a different functionality of Part, or rather the `[[...]]` code.

The `M[[{a,b,c}]]` code gives a *list* of elements of `M` at positions `a,b,c`, rather than the *single* element at the multidimensional position `{a,b,c}`.

Relating to your example, and as you already showed, the code `M[[5,5,5]]` gives the *single* element `0.` at position `{5,5,5}`, whereas the code `M[[{5,5,5}]]` gives the *list* of elements each at position 5 in the first level of `M`.

Comment: I actually laughed at 'the key Part being'... now I feel bad.